# Remove a specific pod from Xcode project

Tags: cocoapods

I need to remove a specific CocoaPod from my Xcode project. Browsing similar questions here on Stack Overflow, I ran into situations where the leading answer caused me to remove all my pods from the project and delete the workspace. Another answer suggested I simply needed to delete the pod from my Podfile and then run `pod install`, but that doesn't work either; I got several errors related to that pod when I went to build the app.

If I check the Pods folder via Finder, the deleted pods are no longer there. However, if I check *Pods > Targets* via the workspace, I still see the pods I deleted. They are also still in the *Pods > pods* directory in the workspace.

For now, I've deleted the related pods from the *Pods > Targets* area and the app builds fine. The pods are still in my *Pods > pods* directory though. Can I delete those? And, should `pod install` be handling all this for me in one go?

Comment: you need to delete the pod file and reinstall it with the pod file you want removed

Answer (score 6):

You deleted specific pods your app. For examples your `podfile`

```
target 'AppTargetName' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'OneSignal'
    pod 'Fabric'

end
```

if You want to delete only `Fabric` pods, you remove this and terminal commant `pod install`
So in the last case;

```
target 'AppTargetName' do
        use_frameworks!

        pod 'Alamofire'
        pod 'SwiftyJSON'
        pod 'OneSignal'

    end
```

Good works :)

Comment: that's what I did however the pod was still located in my targets and in the pod directory in my workspace. Any reason those would hang around after deleting from the pod file and running `pod install`?

Comment: Deletes as a reference when deleting and not trash. But not important you. You can delete what you don't use. If it's true, can you confirm my answer?

Answer (score 2):

## You want to remove specific pods your app. For examples your podfile

#### Your podfile have

```
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
pod 'FirebaseDatabase'
```

#### Remove one of your doesn't need  (pod 'FirebaseDatabase')

```
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
```

#### Then open the terminal of directory of your project podfile

```
pod install
```